# I get the error 'type 'Future' is not a subtype of type 'Future<QuerySnapshot<Object?>>?'

Tags: flutter, dart

```
 User? user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
 List<String> docIDs = [];

Future getDocId() async {
    await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('profiles')
        .where('email', isEqualTo: user?.email)
        .get()
        .then((snapshot) {
      docIDs = [];
      snapshot.docs.forEach((element) {
        docIDs.add(element.reference.id);
      });
    });
  }


               ---------- ----------



child: FutureBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
          future: getDocId(), // Error line
          builder:
              (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
            return ListView.builder(
              itemCount: docIDs.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                final DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot =
                    snapshot.data!.docs[index];
```

I get the error 'type 'Future' is not a subtype of type 'Future<QuerySnapshot<Object?>>?''. How do I define getDocId so I don't get this error?

Comment: `getDocId` is declared to return a `Future`, which is shorthand for `Future<dynamic>`.  The compiler cannot know that it is safe to use it where a `Future<QuerySnapshot<Object?>>` is expected without an explicit cast.  The proper fix is to avoid using `Future<dynamic>` and make the return type more specific.

Answer (score 0):

While you are trying to return docIDs, it can be

```dart
  Future<List<String>> getDocId() async {
    final snapshot = await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('profiles')
        .where('email', isEqualTo: user?.email)
        .get();
    final List<String> docIDs = [];
    for (var element in snapshot.docs) {
      docIDs.add(element.reference.id);
    }
    return docIDs;
  }
```

```dart
 FutureBuilder<List<String>>(
      future: getDocId(), //create sate variable for statefulWidget and use it here
```